# Storing Android App Boolean

Tags: android, boolean

I'm developing an application with an Artificial Neural Network that undergoes a training phase, once complete I will set a Boolean to True.  I need to store this Boolean so that the next time the application is opened it checks to see if the Boolean is True, if it is the Training Phase will not be entered.

Could anyone tell me how to do this? I'd really really appreciate the help as I'm under time constraints!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not, it's a genuine query... sorry to disappoint Inspector Wiser...

Comment: As I didn't know what methodology to use in order to do this I don't feel it is a duplicate..the link you refer to requests information on shared preferences, I don't.  So that didn't answer my question, it aids me now after getting an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It is permanent storage that uses key/value pairs to store data. I could give an example but there are plenty on SO.

[Docs Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[SO examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124713/shared-preference-android)

Comment: Brilliant stuff folks!! Ill give that a shot! Hopefully ye won't hear from me again!!

Comment: Actually could this be used to pass variables between activities/intents?

Comment: Sure, you can get the value from there if you need then pass it.