# How to use CheckBox to enable/disable the vibration and tone in Android

Tags: android, notifications, vibration

I am working on a settings Activity, and I need to enable or disable vibration/tone. I need to learn how to do these two functionalities in my app. I am also providing a snapshot of the setting Activity. I have tried this code for vibration but I do not know how to use this code in check box.

```
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);  
vib.vibrate(500);
Toast.makeText(this, "vib started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to store checkbox value in **SharedPreference** 
see this link **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124713/shared-preference-android/35425731#35425731)**

Then check this store value using condition and execute that vibrate and ring code.

```
  AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

   audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```